# If $4a + b = 3$ then $20a + 5b =$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is this solvable? I think not, I think something is missing.

Am i wrong?

```
If 4a + b = 3 then 20a + 5 = ?
a. 15
b. 1/4
c. 4/3
d. 3/4
```

Comment: That problem must have a typo: it should be asking about $20a+5b$, which of course is $15$.

Comment: perhaps the edit which corrects the typo is not so helpful...

Comment: @Ronald: I think I see what you're saying. Brian's comment looks as though it's correcting an error that isn't there...

Comment: I find this a bit strange to get tagged "linear algebra" instead of "precalculus", maybe that's just me.  I mean, in linear algebra, don't you try and find all solutions to equations like ((4*a)+b)=3?  Digressing, ((4*a)+b)=3 has an infinity of solutions which you can describe by a line, or equivalently an infinite set of pairs on the reals.  All members of the set of pairs have form 
(a, (3-(4*a))).  So, (1, -1), (2, -5), (3, -9), etc. all work as particular solutions for ((4*a)+b)=3, though of course this isn't what this question is asking.  The tag "linear-algebra" just trips me up here.

Comment: @Doug: Feel free to change it!

Answer (score 3):

You are quite correct: something has to be missing. No matter what value you give $a$, there is a value of $b$ that makes the first equation true, so $20a+5$ is indeterminate.

From the answers given, it’s clear that the second expression was supposed to be $20a+5b$; since this is $5(4a+b)$, the intended correct answer must be $15$.

Comment: Ok thanks, That sounds about right.

Answer (score 0):

You got 1 equation with 2 unknowns and you're trying to find the first one (finding 20a+5 requires a). Therefore it's unsolvable.

Comment: Thanks!, thats what I thought.